# Error installing pandas on Windows 10

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I try to install pandas using the following command `python -m pip install pandas`.
Unfortunately, I always get the following error (I think the error throws installing numpy):

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Files.obj'

error: Command "C:\Users\flori\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\PCbuild /LIBPATH:build\temp.win32-2.7 /EXPORT:init_dummy build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\numpy\core\src\dummymodule.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-2.7\numpy\core\_dummy.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\numpy\core\src\_dummy.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\numpy\core\src\_dummy.pyd.manifest" failed with exit status 1181
```

Does someone know this error?

Thank you alot!

Comment: As an aside I strongly suggest you use an integrated python distribution such as [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [winpython](https://winpython.github.io/) this will massivley simplify your life

Comment: I would use an already built numpy version http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and then install pandas. It seems there are a couple of bugs reported dealing with double quotes in Windows and directories with spaces in case you want to have a look. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2611

Comment: Sorry for being very but installing anaconda solved to issue for me!